# MySQL Master/Master replication working only one way

Tags: mysql, database, replication

I have two mysql databases. I want to do a master/master replication.

Replication is working one way. However, the other way it does not. The error states that it can't connect with user 'test@IPADDRESS'.

How can I change the username to repl? Never put in test, so not sure how it even trying to connect with that user. Doesn't exist in the user table either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [CHANGE MASTER TO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/change-master-to.html) command (run from the 'slave'). It's the MASTER_USER you're after.